# Will Heroku ACM renew revoked Let's Encrypt certificates?

Tags: heroku, lets-encrypt

Several of my domains are managed via Automated Certificate Management. Today, [Let's Encrypt announced](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/revoking-certain-certificates-on-march-4/114864) that, due to a misconfiguration on their end, they plan on revoking certificates issued during a certain time period. I checked my certs, and several of them will be revoked.

Does Heroku plan on proactively renewing these revoked certs? If not, what can I do to minimize disruption to my applications?

Comment: Why not ask the Heroku support such questions?

Comment: Heroku recommends one ask questions on StackOverflow, so I did assuming it worked the way some other communities do, with official reps participating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heroku responded with a knowledge base article stating that they will handle renewal for the affected certificates](https://help.heroku.com/APX3CBOH/let-s-encrypt-certificate-revocation).

Specifically,

> Those apps that would be affected by this revocation have had the ACM process re-run for them automatically.